# Discrepancy in Google Analytics data when using segments

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having a tough time with Google Analytics, trying to understand why the value of metrics changes when segments are applied.

There is a standard audience overview report, which is based on 100% of sessions (no sampling) and the view is not filtered. The period is March of 2017.

Standard "All visitors" segment looks like this:

[image]

Then, there is another built-in segment called "Bounced Sessions". When I apply this segment, the "All visitors" values changes:

[image]

Amount of users increases, but the count of pageviews decreases.

Any ideas how to explain this?.. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oki, there can be, multiple reasons. Let me explain first how these numbers are calculated, then we move on to your query.

There two types of data gathering and manipulation from google.

***Pre-calculated data*** -- *pre-aggregated tables*

These are the precalculated data that Google uses to speed up the UI. Google does not specify when this is done but it can be at any point of the time. These are known as pre-aggregated tables

***Data calculated on the fly***

Some that you do which result in computation or manipulation falls under this category. Like using segments, creating custom reports etc.

---

Coming to your problem. When you apply segment, every metric that it effects will be calculated again. Thus it may result in numbers greater than you see in normal view.

Standard audience overview report is pre-aggregated at some point of the day. When you apply segment, the results will be calculated with the fresh data. Since latter is the latest, it will automatically give you increased number of the metrics. Even you can see a decrease as well, all depends on your data and user behavior.

---

***Resolution***: If you are a premium user, use Big Query. You must rely on big query for every metric as they are fresh and calculated on the fly

---

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment!

I've heard about the pre-calculated data however, I don't understand how this could happen here. I'm trying to analyse the period which happened in the past and data is unlikely to change (March of 2017).


I was wondering, could this happen because "All users" segment is based on user scope and "Bounced sessions" based on session scope?

Comment: Yes, one of the highest probability is because of the scope. When you apply the segments, metrics will be recalculated. TBH, this discrepancy is very normal. Are you a premium GA user? @user3371019

Comment: Nope, regular GA user here. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @user3371019 no probs :)

Comment: See my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261736/google-analytics-bug-when-choosing-country-segments. In my case, I had a discrepancy of 143 versus 114 in the number of transactions, just by changing dates and usinging segments. I did not expect a perfect match as if it were an accounting application. But a discrepancy of 143 versus 114 for the number of transactions in a segment for a single day May 8th seemed inacceptable to me for these Google Analytics reports, regardless of how Google Analytics does its work to compute and present those values.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya I replied to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261736/google-analytics-bug-when-choosing-country-segments